# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7 after refresh

Tags: java, android

Everything works fine until it is refreshed. App crashes when the new record is clicked after being refreshed.

In my main class

```
  mPullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshView)view.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh);
        mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshView.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mPullToRefreshView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask(getActivity()).execute();
                    }
                }, 10);
            }
        });
```

In my asynctask class

```
class RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private String TAG = RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private String TAG_PID = "pid";
    public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;
    //URL to get JSON details
    private String url = "http://localhost/abc.php";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sales_details;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    String jsonStr;
    JSONArray sales;

    //for recycler view
    private RecyclerView warehouse_recycler;
    private AdapterRecycler mAdapter;
    List<WarehouseSalesDetails> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public RetrieveWarehouseSalesTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sales_details = new ArrayList<>();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting you the best warehouse sales...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        //making a request to URL and getting response
        jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if(jsonStr != null){
            try{
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                //Getting JSON Array Node
                sales = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result");
                //looping through all results
                for(int i = 0; i<sales.length();i++){
                    JSONObject s = sales.getJSONObject(i);
                    WarehouseSalesDetails wsd = new WarehouseSalesDetails();
                    wsd.expiry_date = s.getString("expiry_date");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date actual_date = sdf.parse(wsd.expiry_date);
                    if(new Date().before(actual_date)){
                        wsd.id = s.getString("id");
                        wsd.company_name = s.getString("company_name");
                        wsd.promotion_image= s.getString("promotion_image");
                        wsd.title = s.getString("title");
                        wsd.promotional_period = s.getString("promotional_period");
                        wsd.viewCount = s.getString("view_count");
                        data.add(wsd);
                    }
                }
                Log.d("TAG",sales_details.toString());
            }catch(final JSONException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG,"Couldn't get json from server");
        }
        //update RecyclerView
        warehouse_recycler = (RecyclerView)((AppCompatActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mAdapter = new AdapterRecycler(context, data);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        warehouse_recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        warehouse_recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        warehouse_recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context,warehouse_recycler,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        WarehouseSalesDetails wsd = data.get(position);
                       // Toast.makeText(context,"ID is " + wsd.id,
                                //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String pid = wsd.id;
                        Intent in = new Intent(context,RetrieveIndividualWarehouseSales.class);
                        in.putExtra("pid",pid);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position){
                        //do whatever
                    }
                }));
        mPullToRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
    }

}
```

Logcat points the error to this line

```
WarehouseSalesDetails wsd = data.get(position);
```

Logcat message

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
```

It could be due to the arraylist unable to store the latest record after being refreshed. How should I go about this problem ?

Comment: -1 to the position? because Android starts the first integer at 1 for position and ArrayLists have it at 0 so it's programatically easier for you to solve further issues if all of the integers are the same.

Comment: @Nicholas, it displays the details of the item in position - 1. Not really solving the problem.

Comment: Its Means Your Adapter Has 8 Items   But your Data List have only 7 .Check How many items are there in your Adapter ?, I think you miss some where .

Comment: I/System.out: mAdapter size is: 17
I/System.out: Data size is: 17... @ChetanJoshi . After adding a new record to db and I refreshed the app. Both size match but when I clicked on the new record, the app crashes. The error is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 16, Size: 16

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by implementing onClick method in the adapter class itself

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    WarehouseSalesDetails wsd = data.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    String pid = wsd.id;
                    Intent in = new Intent(context,RetrieveIndividualWarehouseSales.class);
                    in.putExtra("pid",pid);
                    context.startActivity(in);
                }
            });
```